# Dapper For MySQL Query<T>(string sql) sql has a custom variables(@rowNum) contains a special character @

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

Here is my question.I want to get a User Page List and I do not want to use limit.then I get to use sql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT @rowNum:=@rowNum+1 AS rowNum,User FROM (SELECT
@rowNum:=0) r,User where User.Name=@Name ORDER BY User.Name) AS a
WHERE rowNum>=1  AND rowNum<=10
```

.net code like this:

```
connection.Query<T>(sql, new{Name="name"}, transaction, true,commandTimeout);
```

and when I run the program,it throw an exception:

```
message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
data: { },
innerException: null,
stackTrace: " at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_ServerThread() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Abort() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior) at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__124`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) at Infrastructure.Dapper.MysqlMapperExtension.QueryPaged[T](IDbConnection connection, Object condition, String table, String orderBy, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, String columns, Boolean isOr, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout) in E:\Lofter\Code Source\NetCore\MermaidLoft.Alchemy\MermaidLoft.Alchemy\src\Extensions\Infrastructure.Dapper\MysqlMapperExtension.cs:line 312 at MermaidLoft.Alchemy.BaseDomain.UserDomain.UserQueryService.FindUsersForPage(String userName, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize) in E:\Lofter\Code Source\NetCore\MermaidLoft.Alchemy\MermaidLoft.Alchemy\src\Domains\MermaidLoft.Alchemy.BaseDomain\UserDomain\UserQueryService.cs:line 30 at MermaidLoft.Alchemy.QuickWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Mysql() in E:\Lofter\Code Source\NetCore\MermaidLoft.Alchemy\MermaidLoft.Alchemy\src\MermaidLoft.Alchemy.QuickWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 40",
helpLink: null,
source: "SapientGuardian.MySql.Data",
hResult: -2147467261
```

Is there any idea to solve this problem?Hope some can help me,Thx!

Comment: Take a look at this :https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57671

Comment: it run good: connection.QueryList<User>(new { Id=userId}, ConfigSettings.UserTable).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you want to check username does not special character or something like that >> that easy you can make loop for each char in string and cast char to int now you convert char to ascii and check it by if

```
string x="aaaa";
foreach(char a in x)
{
     int s=(int)a;
    //(s>=65&&s<=90) capital
    //(s>=97&&s<=122) small 
    if((s>=65&&s<=90) || (s>=97&&s<=122))
               //do your code

}
```

Comment: sorry，it's my problem,now I edit my question again.I want to solve how to use custom variables(@rowNum) contains a special character @.